# reactjs forfeit current component render

Tags: reactjs

**Scenario**

Depending on the data coming into props I may want my component to render but I also may NOT want my component to rerender.

**Code**

Currently I'm using `if(!props.data) return null` but this merely sends back a blank component.

**Question**

How can I forfeit the render so that my current dom element stays unchanged, leaving the last rendered content intact? I'm wanting my component only update when `props.data` has a truthy value.

Comment: It is not totally clear what you are trying to achieve. You only want your component to update if `props.data` has changed? Also which version of react are you using?

Comment: Also could you elaborate on why you want to do this in the first place? There might be a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data received in a local state and only update it if `props.data` changes and has a truthy value like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
    const [localData, setLocalData] = useState(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) setLocalData(data);
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <div>{localData}</div>
    );
};
```

But note that this has a little bit of a design smell. Why does your component receive new props in the first place if it shouldn't update. The correct place to hold that state may be in a component further up the tree.

Comment: This is a redux component so sometimes when the redux store is updated this component will also re render (the value I'm evaluating is not coming from props but from a redux store). I ommitted those details to keep my question as basic as possible. I ended up store a "last" value on the component itself - using similar logic to what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to try using conditional rendering of the component if the `data` is present in the parent instead of checking the props within the component.

```
function ParentComponent(props) {
      const data = <your custom data>;
      if(data) {
        return <ChildComponent data={data} />;
      }
    }
```